# Android Change view content while invisible

Tags: android, view

I have two layouts, which have views inside that have changeable content and I switch between them by making them VISIBLE and INVISIBLE

Contents of view depends on response of REST service and I have to change content of specified view when response is got.

But REST service runs on background which doesn't wait for the layout which is VISIBLE.

I am applying changes to related views within Runnable called in runOnUIThread from background Thread

It looks OK so far, but is it OK to make changes on INVISIBLE layout's child View?

Sample:

when HTTP 200 is returned from server:

```
public void success(retrofit.client.Response response, retrofit.client.Response ignore) {
                String out = new String();

                TypedInput body = response.getBody();
                try {
                    out = getString(response);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                     txtStuCounter.setText(out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

and TimerTask switches between views with calling function below depending on time:

```
private void showHideCourse(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        if (isMultiple == false) {
            layoutCourse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutMCourse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtStuCounter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            layoutMCourse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutCourse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtStuCounter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (!noSchedule) {
            //DersProgrami yururlukte
            layoutSchedule.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            isSchedule = false;
        } else {
            //Toplanti salonu videosu
            logoView.stopPlayback();
            wasVideoPlaying = false;
            logoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code to get help in a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Loaders are the best solution to your problem to load data in backGround
and update UI
See Example:

```
private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> favouriteLoaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>(getContext()) {


            @Override
            protected void onStartLoading() {
                forceLoad();
            }

            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground() {
// do your back ground work here  ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor mCursor) {

       // set you visibilty Here... 
}
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
};
then intit the loaser in onCreate Methode



getLoaderManager().initLoader(FAVOURITE_LOADER_ID, null, favouriteLoaderCallbacks);
```

Read More 
[Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: Where should I change related views' content?  Should I change visibility of view to VISIBLE before changing it's content on onLoadFinished?

Comment: on onLoadFinished called you can set content and change visibilty of your layout

Comment: but I want to change content of INVISIBLE views, I want to be sure if it is OK to change content if that view is invisible?

Comment: I am sure it is **OK** i have tested it for You .

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am trying it now

Comment: You are Welcome :)))

Answer (score 1):

use this one in xml layout

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

or use this inside your class

```
object.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: But, wouldn't it cause background Thread to change content of a view which have visibility value of View.GONE ?